# Famo.us Prevent Scrollview Bounce

Tags: javascript, angularjs, famo.us

I can't seem to find the correct set of scrollView options to disable the overscroll/bounce effect. I'm using the last example on this page:
https://famo.us/integrations/angular/docs/unstable/api/directive/faScrollView/index.html

End goal is to have a sidebar menu like every single app ever made in the last 5 years. You would think it would be a more popular example for this framework, but I can't seem to find any useful ones for FA.

Answer (score 0):

I have been told multiple times that setting edgeGrip : 1 in the options will make it no longer bounce. It doesn't work for me and no ones showed me a fiddle where it does work. I don't use the angular integrated version of famo.us so I'm not sure I can be of much help.

I personally used a generic sync and built a scrollview with that. Its similar to how the draggable works. Which is what i suggest, the draggable can give you a 'scroller' without a bounce. The down side is it won't be smart enough to not render things outside it's view. For my use I was building a form that was maybe twice the height of the screen and it works fine. If you want the non angular / straight famo.us version I use let me know. Hope the edgeGrip works for you.